# PHP How to explode string using multiple regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a long string consisting of a series of segments separated by a single character `~`.

Example:

```
ST*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*~IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*~TDS*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*~
```

Notice that this is a single string with no new lines at all. I just formatted it for readability.

The output should be:

```
Array{
      [0]=>ST*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*

      [1]=>Array{
                 [0]=>IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*  
                 [1]=>IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here 
                 [2]=>IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*  
                }

      [2]=>TDS*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*
}
```

How can this output be generated from the input string?

The thing is I can only guarantee that the beginnings of these segments (`ST`, `IT1`, `TDS`) as they are mandatory, but they may be followed by random number of optional segments.

Of course the separator `~` may only occur between segments and not inside them.

**UPDATE:** I need the string to be exploded into 3 parts:

1. The string starting from `ST` till the first occurrence of `IT1`.
2. The collection of strings starting by `IT1` and ending by the next `IT1`.
3. The final string starting by `TDS` till the end of the string.

Comment: @L0j1k I modified the post to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, I would use preg_split:

```
$var = '~' . "ST*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*~IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*~TDS*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*~";

$split = preg_split('/~(ST|IT1|TDS)/', $var, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$blocks = array('ST' => array(), 'IT1' => array(), 'TDS' => array());

for($i = 1; $i < count($split); $i+=2)
{
    $blocks[$split[$i]][] = $split[$i] . $split[$i+1];
}

var_dump($blocks);
```

Notes:

1. I prepend `~` to make things easier on the split
2. I start $i as 1 because the first split will be empty

**Result**

```
array(3) {
  ["ST"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(70) "ST*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*"
  }
  ["IT1"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(53) "IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*"
    [1]=>
    string(35) "IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here"
    [2]=>
    string(71) "IT1*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*"
  }
  ["TDS"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(72) "TDS*Any*Characters*are*allowed*here~optional*segment*~optional*segment*~"
  }
}
```

Comment: "How can this output be generated from the input string?"

Comment: Thankfully, he edited in an actual question...

Comment: Perhaps I inferred a question before he edited one in :)

Comment: Absolutely. I just didn't want to see a bunch of downvotes on this  because there wasn't a question. :)

Comment: @CraigMason It seems I confused you with my example. please see my updated post with the example string in its original form without formatting.

Comment: @CraigMason Thanks worked like charm :) +1 and Accepted ;)